# Azure hub notification result.success and result.failure is 0 simultaneously and state enqueued

Tags: azure, notifications

The notifications are sent successfully,but their is no result for push notification as the State : Enqueued f[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zeum3.png)or androidNotificationOutcomeTask.Result
Failure :0 
Result : null

[The result for the sent notification is in attached snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zeum3.png)
Now I want the details Available for sent notification to save that in database,
I have not used property EnableTestSend = true,because I want to send notification more than 10 recipient but I want the details about the notification that I am not getting right now.